# how to extract keys from the string below using c#

Tags: c#, string

**Input query**

```
 select * from mytable where projectname = __$ProjectName$__ and  projectid = __$ProjectId$__ and env = __$EnvType$__
```

I want list of string (`List<string>`) as output below.(double underscore+dollar+"string"+dollar+double underscore)
Language: C#

```
 __ $ProjectName$__
 __ $ProjectId$__
 __ $EnvType$__
```

Comment: You can use regular expression, something like `(__\$[^\$]+\$__)` and get all matches with Regex class

Comment: Use string join "&__&"  Then add to beginning "_$" and to end "&_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try *regular expressions*; if key

1. *Starts* from `__$`
2. *Contains* *identifier* (which starts from letter `A..Z`, `a..z`, can contain letters or\and digits `A..Z`, `a..z`, `0..9`)
3. *Ends* with `$__`

the pattern to match is `__\$[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*\$__`

**Code:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = 
  "select * from mytable where projectname = __$ProjectName$__ and  projectid = __$ProjectId$__ and env = __$EnvType$__";

List<string> keys = Regex
  .Matches(source, @"__\$[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*\$__")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToList();

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, keys));
```

**Outcome:**

```
__$ProjectName$__
__$ProjectId$__
__$EnvType$__
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Linq:

```
List<string> output = input.Split(' ').Where(x => x.StartsWith("__$") && x.EndsWith("$__")).ToList();
```

Comment: Be careful with splitting by space: if query is `...where projectname=__$ProjectName$__ and ...` (please, notice *abscence of space* after `=`) the `__$ProjectName$__ ` key will not be extracted

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var expression = @"select * from mytable where projectname = __$ProjectName$__ and  projectid = __$ProjectId$__ and env = __$EnvType$__";

            var output = new Regex(@"__\$[^\s]+?\$__")
                .Matches(expression)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();

            output.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regex [may match](https://regex101.com/r/JY5847/1) empty strings and blank strings